# Update to Percise seems to have broke everything display wise, my screen is now a mirrored garbled mess that is entirely unreadable. Help?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

Update to Percise seems to have broke everything display wise, my screen is now a mirrored garbled mess that is entirely unreadable. Any ideas on how to get it working again?

For obvious reasons I can't really give many more details, I've attempted to reinstall flgrx and even to SSH in, but for some reason I can't even get the network services running.

Any tips on how to force a return to the default drivers from a command line I can do little more than type into and pray?

Comment: If you can get on to IRC, ask about it at #ubuntu-desktop. They were very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command and then restarting your machine.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Found from here: [How do I remove the FGLRX drivers after I've installed them by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78675/how-do-i-remove-the-fglrx-drivers-after-ive-installed-them-by-hand)

Comment: That has got me to a loading screen that seems endless, however things are at least legible again, thanks! My purge must of missed one of those.