# My desktop is gone

Tags: unity

My unity desktop is gone after running these commands

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Not sure how to get it back. I'm running chrome through the terminal

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Looking at ccsm, the unity plugin seems enabled. I really don't know what to do :(

currently, my desktop looks like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xznxinitg2yrhtp/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-30%2018%3A17%3A57.png

---

@nerof61 - I have tried his suggestion by running the command

```
sudo unity --replace
sudo unity -- reset
```

and the results are still the same.

Here are some of the messages that shows in my terminal after running these two commands.

```
- Info: Loading plugin: core compiz (core) 
- Info: Starting plugin: core unity-panel-service: no process found compiz (core) 
- Info: Loading plugin: reset compiz (core) 
- Error: Failed to load plugin: reset compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp compiz (core) 
- Info: Starting plugin: ccp compizconfig 
- Info: Backend : gsettings compizconfig 
- Info: Integration : true compizconfig 
- Info: Profile : default compiz (core) 
- Info: Loading plugin: composite compiz (core) 
- Info: Starting plugin: composite (process:6575): 
GLib-WARNING **: In call to g_spawn_sync(), exit status of a child process was requested but SIGCHLD action was set to SIG_IGN and ECHILD was received by waitpid(), so exit status can't be returned. This is a bug in the program calling g_spawn_sync(); either don't request the exit status, or don't set the SIGCHLD action. ** (process:6575): WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
Error spawning command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=fbaaf03a47625e9ba0cde97e0000000a --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 59
```

@nerof61 - unfortunately, I have a slow connection today and can't afford to download GNONE or others.. Is there any other way for this?

@Htet Kyaw Lwin - as per your suggestion, I've tried to remove the driver I've installed using this commands

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Actually, only the second run. Then I rebooted my system and it's still the same. Still the top navigation and side navigation is missing.

I appreciate all the help.

---

[SOLVED]

@Htet Kyaw Lwin - I've tried to go back to your suggestion, but this time, I specified only 1 item to be purged

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

Then tried to reboot and now it's back! Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall your graphic card driver and reboot your computer.

[How do I remove the FGLRX drivers after I've installed them by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78675/how-do-i-remove-the-fglrx-drivers-after-ive-installed-them-by-hand)

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

At the command line, type:

```
sudo unity --replace
```

You can also try:

```
sudo unity -- reset
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: Edit your post.

Comment: ** (process:6575): WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=fbaaf03a47625e9ba0cde97e0000000a --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 59
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22

Comment: Hmm... start CCSM by typing into terminal `ccsm`.

Comment: On the left-hand side, there should be a plug-in called `Ubuntu Unity Plug-in`. Is the box ticked?

Comment: Oh... this is getting tricky.

Comment: What does `unity --replace` do?

Comment: Ok... have a felling this is going to be hard...

Comment: Switch to tty1 (Ctrl + Alt + F1), log in and then type `startx`. Any errors? You could also when logged in go back to tty7 (Ctrl + Alt + F7).

Comment: tty7? Did it work?

Comment: Hmm... can you install GNOME? Or some other desktop enviroment?

Comment: Then you can re-install Unity from the Software Center.

Comment: @TeodyC.Seguin - please reply to queries by editing your question - asking and responding through comments makes it difficult for others to understand the current state of the question.  Please do so now and delete your comments thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedome.. oh i got it, sorry i'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

good to know that your problem is solved. but i happened to post this just 4 minutes after you solved your problem! :p

---

ORIGINAL:

is the unity greeter (the default login screen) visible when you boot ubuntu? or is that gone too?
if it is visible, then the problem might be with unity. you could try installing the gnome desktop and see if that works.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

i've noticed on my own desktop (which has nvidia geforce 900) that the driver breaks unity (and maybe even all of ubuntu). it showed junk characters at first just before unity greeter could start. later on, as i began using an application (frescobaldi, to be precise) the whole desktop crashed and unity greeter just wouldn't start. i uninstalled the driver, (through tty1) and that broke the X-server too. *:-(*

i had to recover my files through live cd and reinstall ubuntu. never again did i install those *proprietary* drivers!

Comment: oh.. thanks for attempt to help, I appreciate it :).. Yes it is visible during login. Then after I go logged in, it just got plain (only the desktop background shows)