# Installing new ATI drivers, running into issues

Tags: drivers, ati, updates, graphics, fglrx

I'm trying to install "amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64" for my HD 7850, but I'm having issues getting my old driver uninstalled (which I got from "fglrx-updates" under software sources). I followed the instructions in "[How do I remove the FGLRX drivers after I've installed them by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78675/how-do-i-remove-the-fglrx-drivers-after-ive-installed-them-by-hand)", but once the second command finished, the drivers were still detected by the installer I first mentioned.

Would I need to restart or use an entirely different command? The last thing I would want to do is screw up my graphics.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install them from the .run file, or did you generate .deb packages from the .run file?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

to remove any drivers installed using the package system.