# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 5548

Tags: drivers, partitioning, ati, dell

I recently purchased Dell Inspiron 5548 with a pre-installed Windows 8 OEM on a HDD 1TB with Single Partition. Is it possible to install Ubutnu 14.04 on it? Is there issues related for my model for bluetooth, wifi drivers and working?

How can I partition the disk into multiple partitions so as to install Ubuntu 14.04 on separate disk partition. I don't want to remove Current Windows 8 completely ( as I need it to use softwares like Photoshop etc).

Also my laptop comes with 2GB ATI Graphics Card, will I able to get benefits/ use graphics card in Ubuntu? Do I need to install proprietary drivers in Ubuntu to use graphics card? If Yes, where can I get those drivers for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes you can install Ubuntu in your computer. Just download Ubuntu iso and make a bootable USB. Follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) post for more information. You have to really take care of 'secure boot' and 'fast boot' and UEFI partitions. You can create one big partition or separate partition (for `/boot`, `/home`, `swap`, `/`, etc) for Ubuntu from within windows 8 by giving as much space as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu "beside" your Windows installation. There will be an option to install this way. But before you install Ubuntu make sure that Windows is properly shut down. By default Windows 8 is hibernated instead.

You can use open source or proprietary video drivers. Proprietary drivers can be installed from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

You do not need to look for the drivers elsewhere.

Comment: I have exactly the same model, and this did not work for me.

Comment: I guess, you can write what worked for you then as an answer :-)

Comment: I only meant the part with the proprietary drivers.That would be true, however I have not managed to install the proprietary drivers at all (Following System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers leads to Unity not loading and me having to uninstall as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78675/how-do-i-remove-the-fglrx-drivers-after-ive-installed-them-by-hand. I can therefore not provide an answer. Other than that though the laptop works perfectly with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score -1):

yes u can install it. 
simple process of installing : 1) wubi
                               2) install Ubuntu in different BIOS MODE
                                  i.e other than in which windows is     installed(UEFI OR LEGACY are two BIOS MODE)